# Streamlining jQuery code with the HTML 5 Boilerplate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html5boilerplate

I'm following the [h5bp](http://html5boilerplate.com) proposed pattern of slapping all your script files on the bottom of the page, save for [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Now, here's me working on something in ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm creating extensions to the `HtmlHelper` to compartmentalize the markup of some reusable elements / controls on the form. Something like `@Html.GiveMeATableDammit()` would generate markup for a table.

My dilemma comes in right about here. What if the markup generated requires some jQuery to be run against it? To illustrate, let's say that a jQuery plugin function needs to be called against that table:

```
@Html.GiveMeATableDammit("a-very-dirty-mouthed-table")

//
// will generate customized HTML
<table id="a-very-dirty-mouthed-table">
    <!-- some more stuff -->
</table>
<script>
    // along with customized javascript to match
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#a-very-dirty-mouthed-table').giveMeSuperPowers();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, at the point of markup generation, jQuery doesn't exist yet, since jQuery is at the bottom of the page.

Now, *barring the idea of moving jQuery to `<head>`*, how can I hold off the execution of that one function until the very end of the page, where jQuery already exists?

Comment: Can you not keep your JavaScript in JavaScript-files?

Comment: @powerbuoy ~ entirely not the point. If I slap on a `<script src="foo.js"></script>` in place of the inline script block in the question, I'm still left with the same problem.

Comment: Yes, but how about you just have ONE script element right before the closing body tag (as per the html5boilerplate best practices (and general best practices (caching, performance, code separation))) and that one JS file is a merge of all your separate JS files for each module/part of the page. I've never worked with ASP.NET MVC but fail to see why this would be a problem?

Comment: Then my question becomes, how do you tell the page to include this particular piece of script if I somehow call `@Html.GiveMeATableDammit()` on my page? How about `@Html.AnotherControl()`? The h5bp proposal does recommend on a singular JS file, yes, but (if it wasn't clear in the question) how would it best handle something modular as the pattern above? The thesis being not including any script unless it's otherwise needed, and that scripts can adapt to the markup.

Comment: @powerbuoy ~ edited the code to make that more apparent.

Comment: Unless there's a _huge_ amount of JavaScript (more than twice the size of jQuery at least) I would just go ahead and include all script at once. That way it's cached after one page load and your HTML files (and backend) are free from JS (which in turn makes the HTML smaller). To make sure you only run the code when it's needed you could do something as simple as `if ($('#awesome-table').length) AwesomeTable.init()`.

Comment: Agreed. However if I was caching a single JS file for the entire site, then that leaves me highly inflexible to changing my selectors, for example. What if my table wasn't `#awesome-table`? I do see where you're coming from, and I get it, and I understand the benefits of singular resource file dependency, but let's suspend that for a moment and consider this thesis for the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some ASP magic to do this, one approach I've seen is to declare an array in the `<head>` of your page, and `push()` your `ready` handlers to them, then, at the bottom (*after* jQuery) has loaded, run them:

`<head>`:

```
var handlers = [];
```

Wherever:

```
handlers.push(function ($) {
    $('#a-very-dirty-mouthed-table').giveMeSuperPowers();
});
```

`</body>`:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
    handlers.forEach(function (val) {
        jQuery(document).ready(val);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I do recall reading something to this effect somewhere (most probably SO), even to the point of aliasing `$(document).ready()` to point to the `[].push()` call. Nonetheless, a good idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Found it : http://blog.colin-gourlay.com/blog/2012/02/safely-using-ready-before-including-jquery/

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan, see my answer for the history of that post.

Answer (score 1):

[From my blog](http://blog.vervestudios.co/blog/post/2011/07/01/How-to-Setup-jQueryready-Callbacks-Before-jQuery-is-Loaded.aspx) on the subject:

```
<head>
    <script>
        (function(a){
            _q=function(){return a;};
            $=function(f){
                typeof f==="function" && a.push(arguments);
                return $;
            };
            jQuery=$.ready=$;
        }([]));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#main" ).prepend( "<p>Heyo!</p>" );
            });
        </script>
        <div>...more HTML...</div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function( i, s, q, l ) {
            for( q = window._q(), l = q.length; i < l; ) {
                $.apply( this, s.call( q[ i++ ] ) );
            }
            window._q = undefined;
        }( 0, Array.prototype.slice ));
    </script>
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

> What the first `<script>` does is emulate jQuery's ready function by storing the arguments of any calls to `$.ready` where the first argument is a function into an array. This array is private to our globally scoped _q method, which, when called, returns the array.
>
> The last inline `<script>` loops through the array by calling `_q()` and then applies the arguments originally passed to our imposter `$.ready` to the real `$.ready`.

[Sam Saffron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) independently came up with a [similar method](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax) about a year later to fix the same issue here on Stack Overflow.

In response to Sam's post, Colin Gourlay came up with an even [more robust method](http://blog.colin-gourlay.com/blog/2012/02/safely-using-ready-before-including-jquery/) (which is probably overkill).

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. This definitely was the post I read before. :) And yeah, I thought that support for `.bind('ready', fn)` was a bit of overkill as well. +1